# broadcast action on permission change in android M

Tags: android

does application gets any broadcast or any kind of alert when its permission setting is changed from Settings? I have got a scenario where  we start some kind of logging when application starts and has got LOCATION GROUP permissions. But when user revokes this permission in between our application crashes. Not finding any way to stop the logging when user cancels it. This logging is from 3rd party library so we can not put any check permission check too in between.

Comment: there are no broadcasts, all you can do is check to see if the permissions has been granted or not

Comment: That kinda suxors, especially if you have a service that is running in the background with a *required*, prompted and approved permission, but someone mucks w/ permissions and denies it *while* it is running. Without an event to be told that the permission changed, the service will appear to keep running as normal. It will have to follow the naively recommended practice of testing for permissions for every call to the already approved permission. It would be better to catch an event and pause the service and prompt with a first-class notification that permission is required to resume.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> does application gets any broadcast or any kind of alert when its permission setting is changed from Settings?

Not that is documented.

If the user revokes a permission that was previously granted to you, your process will be terminated. When you next run, you will wind up finding out about the permission change as part of checking for permissions.

If the user grants a permission that was previously denied, your process is *not* terminated. However, once again, when you call `checkSelfPermission()`, you will find out that you have access.

The lesson here is: do not cache permission lookup results. They seem to be fairly cheap calls, so just call `checkSelfPermission()` as needed.

If your `targetSdkVersion` is below 23, `checkSelfPermission()` will not help, but you should be getting bogus data rather than a `SecurityException`. In the case of location fixes, you should not get any locations if the user has revoked your location access permissions.

> But when user revokes this permission in between our application crashes

I have not tried a scenario where a background service is running and the user revokes a permission. It *should* be terminating your process, and so you would find out about the permission change when your service runs for the next time. If you are finding that your process is *not* being terminated, that may be a sign of a bug in Android.

Comment: Actually I am able to revoke permission from the settings/App and  then able to switch back to my app.

Comment: I revoked permission and now when I do ps i dont see process running but my application is still there in recent apps list and  I am able to launch it from there. Is there any way I can clean it from recent apps list too?

Comment: @SumitShrivastava: "but my application is still there in recent apps list" -- sure. On Android 5.0+, it will be there pretty much forever. "Is there any way I can clean it from recent apps list too? " -- not when the user toggles permissions in Settings. Please explain what problem is being caused by your app appearing in the overview/recent-apps screen.

Comment: We have got a third party library for logging and this library has one alarm. Broadcast receiver of this alarm looks for current location. We have got only two options either we can start logging or stop logging.  When app starts with the location permissions, we start logging. Now we go to settings and revoke location permission and open this application again from recent apps list. Our application crashes in broadcast receiver of third party library. I am not finding any way of stopping logging when permission is revoked.

Comment: @SumitShrivastava: So? That does not explain what problem is being caused by your app appearing in the overview/recent-apps screen. There will be **many** cases where your process is not running but that your app will appear in the overview screen. This state is not unique to having permissions revoked.

Comment: I just want to avoid this crash. If application finishes we will have some way of asking for permission again or stopping logging.

Comment: @SumitShrivastava: "Our application crashes in broadcast receiver of third party library" -- then contact the authors of the third-party library to work with them to add Android 6.0 runtime permission support, or stop using that library. Or, determine what it is about your app that causes this crash when your app is started from the recent-tasks list versus being started from a clean start. Clearly, there must be something your app is doing here; otherwise, you would get a crash in the receiver 100% of the time when your app starts up by any means.

Comment: That receiver is  added in our Manifest but the coded in library. We have asked library team to work on permission model too. Thanks for help.

Comment: @CommonsWare When permissions are revoked and the entire process is terminated, when the App is restarted, the last Activity is being launched, is there a way to force the Launcher (as specified in the Manifest) Activity to be started?

Comment: @GaryKipnis: Not directly. This situation is no different than other process-termination situations (e.g., user is in your app, user presses HOME, 5 minutes pass, Android terminates your process to free up system RAM, 5 more minutes pass, user returns to your app, user is sent to whatever activity they had last been on). Have your activities check for expected preconditions and either initialize your state or send the user to the appropriate UI (e.g., authentication screen).

Comment: @GaryKipnis have you figure out any solution to remove last activity from recent list?