# Permission changed callback in Android 6.0

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I wonder if there is some way to being notified when user changes permission in app settings on Android 6.0. I was looking for this answer with no luck. Do you know if it is possible with broadcast receiver and some specific Intent? Or maybe there is some hack to achieve this?

Comment: Whenever a permission is changed in 6.0, `onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) ` is called. You can use any mode from here to notify this.

Comment: onRequestPermissionsResult() isn't called when user change permission in settings

Answer (score 11, accepted):

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718933/broadcast-action-on-permission-change-in-android-m), there is no any broadcast/event that you can intercept when permission revoked from the settings screen by the user.

but the "good" news, in assumption that it's your concern - your process will be terminated automatically by the system if there will be any changes to the permission status while your app process was alive

Comment: However, the Activity that was last open will be recreated. And if it contained a fragment that was originally only created if permissions were given, it will recreate the fragment (even before onCreate of the Activity is called) anyways, even if the permissions are now gone. So checking for permissions must be there, very closely before using them. (At least that is what I observed on android 7.1.1)

Comment: @lucidbrot What can we do to 'reset' the given Activity once it is recreated?  I'm having trouble with that behavior atm.

Comment: @IvanGarza It has been a few years since I last touched Android development, so I don't really know. But if there does not seem to be an easy way to 'reset' the activity, perhaps you can probably react to the event of being brought back and there re-check the permissions. If you don't find anything about it, I am sure there are more knowledgeable people than I who would answer a new question if you write it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of this by using the AlarmManager to periodically check for the permissions your're interested in (for example every 30 seconds) and compare it to the value you saw the last time (saved in SharedPreferences for example). In the worst case you won't get updates within the timer interval, however it should be very unlikely that the user changes a permission multiple times within a short time interval.

Keep in mind that you have to start the periodical checks when the device boots up (android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED).