# How to detect if user disable granted permissions in the settings in android?

Tags: android, android-permissions

In android 6.0 and above the permissions granted at run time and the user can cancel the granted permissions by going to the settings.

I want to run some code just after the user cancels the granted permissions by going to the settings. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198991/permission-changed-callback-in-android-6-0

Comment: applications class don't have onResume method @Anmol.

Comment: make a BaseActivity and extent every activity with that BaseActivity, in the onResume of that BaseActvity check if the permission is granted or not.

Comment: It can't help me @Anmol. because onResume method of an activity doesn't run after the user cancel the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

// call this for checking the permission before other Activity or function //to call

```
if (hasPermission()) {
// do thing

} else {
requestPermissionDialog();
}
```

/////////////////hasPermission////////////////////////////

```
private boolean hasPermission() {
boolean permission = true;
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(WelcomeActivity.this, 
Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
permission = false;
}
return permission;
}
```

//////////////////////////requestPermissionDialog///////////////////////

```
private void requestPermissionDialog() {

    permissionStatus = getSharedPreferences("permissionStatus", MODE_PRIVATE);


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(WelcomeActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_Eenter code hereXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WelcomeActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            //Show Information about why you need the permission
            //  resetPasswordDialog(WelcomeActivity.this,"ok");

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WelcomeActivity.this);
            builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            builder.setTitle("Storage Permission");

            builder.setMessage("This app needs Storage permission.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WelcomeActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        } else if (permissionStatus.getBoolean(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, false)) {
            //Previously Permission Request was cancelled with 'Dont Ask Again',
            // Redirect to Settings after showing Information about why you need the permission


            // resetPasswordDialog(WelcomeActivity.this,"settings");
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WelcomeActivity.this);
            builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);

            builder.setTitle(" Storage Permission");
            builder.setMessage("This app needs Storage permission.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    sentToSettings = true;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Go to Permissions to allow Storage Audio ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        } else {
            //just request the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WelcomeActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
        }

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = permissionStatus.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, true);
        editor.commit();

    }
}
```