# Handling permissions when we disable (revoke) them from app settings

Tags: android, android-permissions, user-permissions

We have an app with some permissions granted. Then an user revokes the permissions from Settings -> App -> Permissions. I mention that the app is in background in this time.

Sometimes, the app crashes when the above flow is happening. Is there any way to handle this ? Can we know when the permission is revoked from app settings ?

I did not find any official documentation related to this subject.

The scenario:

1. Open app and give all the permissions.
2. Click Home button (app in background).
3. Manually revoke the permissions from Settings.
4. Go back to the app -> it crashes

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you check the required permission at onResume?

Comment: What is crash report ?

Comment: I check it at onResume. I saw that some people suggested to check it at onCreate, but it is not working.

Comment: > Further, if permission is revoked by the user, you process will be terminated which was dependent to that critical permission. **Is this applicable to both (android & ios)?**

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing documented about receiving an event when your `runtime permission` is revoked which is granted by the user previously, **So the `Broadcast receiver` won't help here.**

Further, if permission is revoked by the user, you process will be terminated which was dependent to that critical permission.

If the above case fails, you can check with `checkSelfPermission()` call. **In fact checking permission before performing any critical action is a good practice as well**

> Go back to the app -> it crashes

Never happened to me. Or may be I didn't tried ;-) The dependent process must be killed somehow so that you can check when code is called next time. **If you are working with `activity` or `fragment` you should go for `onResume()`, where you can check permission using `checkSelfPermission()`**.

Got reference from [One of the SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718933/broadcast-action-on-permission-change-in-android-m)

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm working with an activity, so I go for onResume().

Comment: You should watch for observers like: getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, contactsObserver);

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether the permission is granted or not, and handle it as per your requirement:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case //location_permission_code:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            } else {

            }
        break;
    }
}
```