# how to restart app when processes doing soft restart?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

Edit: 
I'm afraid my initial question didn't understood the way I intended so I will rephrase it.
Under some circumstances (permission revoke, memory clean) the OS doing a "soft" restart to the application process. When the user reopen the app the OS will launch the last activity used before the precesses restarted. Is there a way to tell the OS to not try to restore the application's last state and just start from the beginning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [broadcast action on permission change in android M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718933/broadcast-action-on-permission-change-in-android-m)

Comment: Editted my question..

Answer (score 0):

Use this https://github.com/JakeWharton/ProcessPhoenix library. You can customize your restarting using this.

Start the default activity in a new process:

`ProcessPhoenix.triggerRebirth(context);`

Or, if you want to launch with a specific Intent:

```
Intent nextIntent = //...
ProcessPhoenix.triggerRebirth(context, nextIntent);
```

If you want to restart application when that goes to background and agin go to foreground use `android:noHistory="true"` for certain activities in android `Manifest.xml` file

Comment: can you explain more specificly how this library solving my issue?

Comment: You can do restarting process using this when permission revoked. You can customize restarting process as well

Comment: but to do so the user will have to first navigate back my application, in one of my activities I will have to recognize the premission revoked and only then I will be able to reset my processes. this could cause a bad user experience.

Comment: How could it be a bad user experience? You need to know where your application going to fail, where it restarts. Otherwise, you create an unpredictable application. You need to control the application when it's state change. This library help for u to customize your restarting

Comment: What I need is not to restart the application after it comes back to foreground but I need the OS to restart my application as it wasn't in the background at all. I don't want it to restore the application state in any process termination. is this possible?

Comment: Put android:noHistory="true" in manifest file for that activity. It will restart application when it going to background

Comment: I don't want it to restart every time it comes back to foreground. only when it comes back after the precesses has restarted which only happen on premission revoke or when the OS clean the processes while the device has low memory.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is still, that the OS does not notify of such an event - which leaves no other option than to manually handle it. eg. check for the permission not being granted `onCreate()` and `onResume()` of the `Activity` - and than act accordingly, eg. clear the back-stack and then inflate the first one fragment.

the only culprit there is split-screen mode, where `onResume()` won't be triggered, simply because it never caused an `onPause()` event. I mean, permission settings on the one side, the application on the other side. to handle this one would have to occasionally check for the state of permissions.