# Can not disable camera permission in PermissionHandler

Tags: android, flutter, dart, permissions

I have been searching for this for a while, in my program, I use [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) to enable camera permission. However, I also want my users to be able to disable the camera permissions programmatically.

Here is the code:

```
                 child: SwitchListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    value: isCameraAllowed,
                    onChanged: (value) async {
                      if(value){
                        var isGranted = await Permission.camera.request().isGranted;
                        if(isGranted){
                          setState(() {
                            isCameraAllowed = value;
                          });
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    title: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(S.current.privacySettingsPageActiveDeactive),
                        Spacer(),
                        Icon(isCameraAllowed ? Icons.videocam : Icons.videocam_off)
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
```

I use **SwichListTile** to indicate either the permission is on or off, so when the user turns tile to **on**, I am able to ask for permission and update it however when the user wants to turn off the permission, I could not find a way to do it. Can anyone help with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, no plugin or package in Flutter supports this feature. What these current plugins/packages do is that they call a native feature to request camera permission.

So, if I request for `Camera` permission, a request goes to the native handler that checks if the permission is granted or not. If not, then it requests for the permission.

You cannot enable or disable an permission directly from the app. It requires a call to the native handler.

Answer (score 1):

You could not find a way to do it. Because there is no way to ask again for **granted** permissions. The user must change the permission from the settings of the app.

Comment: Okay i also assumed that however, when i direct user to app settings, i do not know whether they changed permission or not so i can not update my UI correctly

Comment: I got it. You can follow these steps to modify your UI correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58024956/10659482

Comment: Thank your for the help but when i try this, a crash occurs once i open settings and revoke the permission. And i think it is expected behaviour from the OS, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718933/broadcast-action-on-permission-change-in-android-m

Comment: Some annoying problems. Welcome on board :)